# setProperty() on a JSONModel not triggering property change event

Tags: sapui5

I have a model I use in a controller and have setup both model change and property change event functions on that model like so:

```
onInit: function() {
    var oData = {
        "Products": [ 
        {
            "ProductID": 1,
            "ProductName": "Chai",
            "SupplierID": 1,
            "CategoryID": 1,
            "QuantityPerUnit": "10 boxes x 20 bags",
            "UnitPrice": "18.0000",
            "UnitsInStock": 39,
            "UnitsOnOrder": 0,
            "ReorderLevel": 10,
            "Discontinued": false
        }    
    ]
    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(oData);
    this.attachModelEventHandlers(oModel);
}

attachModelEventHandlers: function(oModel){
    oModel.attachPropertyChange(this.handlePropertyChanged, this);
    var binding = new sap.ui.model.PropertyBinding(oModel, "/", oModel.getContext("/"));
    binding.attachChange(this.handleDataChanged, this);
},

handlePropertyChanged: function(oEvent) {
    // Do whatever here...
}

handleDataChanged: function(oEvent) {
    // Do whatever here...
}
```

I have bound the model to a table and everything works fine... if I update properties, the relevant model change and property change events fire.

If I use something like below to update a property however, only the `handleDataChanged` event function will fire, not the `handlePropertyChanged` event function:

```
oModel.setProperty("Products/0/ProductName", "SomeNewValue");
```

Any idea why? Is my **PropertyBinding** correct?

Answer (score 0):

The SAPUI5 documentation suggests a reason parameter which describes the cause of the property value change. When you update the model with two way bindings using some control like the table in your case, the propertyChange event is fired with the reason sap.ui.model.ChangeReason.Binding. The documentation also says that the event is currently only fired when two way changes occur to a value of a property binding. So directly setting the model property would not trigger the event.

You can check the Events > propertyChange in the [API Reference for sap.ui.model.Model](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/)

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  The reason parameter and the propertyChange event works correctly when used with a control indeed...

Comment: I had read the documentation you linked to and am even more confused now... as it clearly starts by stating: "_The 'propertyChange' event is fired when changes occur to a property value in the model._".

Where does it mention using `setProperty()` will not trigger the property change event please?

Also, I'm open for ideas on fixing this best in my case, which is setting the value of a model property which is bound to the color value of an icon control based on a choice made from a color picker dialog.

Comment: It also says "_Currently the event is only fired with reason sap.ui.model.ChangeReason.Binding which is fired when two way changes occur to a value of a property binding._" So when you change a controls property you are changing the property binding value. However directly changing the model's property using setProperty does not indicate a binding change.

Comment: They way I read this, the event currently ever fires with the particular reason `sap.ui.model.ChangeReason.Binding`... but doesn't clearly mean it should not in my case... but again I believe the documentation could be clearer in this particular case. 

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel also mentions that setProperty should inform all interested parties on a model property change... in my mind that should include registered event handlers for this on the model.

In any case, any suggestions on handling this?  Extend JSONModel to fire the event in my case?